# jQuery and calling a function when radiobutton value changes

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code which calls "valvonta" every 6 seconds. But when a radiobutton value changes, valvonta() is not working at all. It should be executed immediately, not after 6 seconds.

How should I modify my code? Thanks for any help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  valvonta = setInterval(function() {
    var kaavio = 38;

    jQuery.post("hae_tilanteet.php", {
      kaavio: kaavio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#valvonta').html(data);
    });
  }, 6000);

  $('#kaaviotaulukko').change(function(){
    valvonta(); // this does not work
    alert('Radio Box has been changed!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the function properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  valvonta = function() {
    var kaavio = 38;

    jQuery.post("hae_tilanteet.php", {
      kaavio: kaavio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#valvonta').html(data);
    });
  };

  //Pass the function reference to be executed after 6 sec
  setInterval(valvonta,6000);

  $('#kaaviotaulukko').change(function(){
    valvonta(); // this does not work
    alert('Radio Box has been changed!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Should it be like this? setInterval(valvonta(),6000);

Comment: No it should not.

Answer (score 0):

valvonta is not a function, but a unique ID identifying an interval.

Instead name your function like that, not the return value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function valvonta() {  // <---- this changed.
    var kaavio = 38;

    jQuery.post("hae_tilanteet.php", {
      kaavio: kaavio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#valvonta').html(data);
    });
  }, 6000);

  $('#kaaviotaulukko').change(function(){
    valvonta(); // this does not work
    alert('Radio Box has been changed!');
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems to me that "valvonta" is not executed immediately when the radiobutton value changes.

Comment: There will be a slight delay before the HTML changes, but that is because of the request to the server. It depends on how fast you get the result back. But the `alert` will be immediate.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use setInterval and AJAX.
If the server does not respond, you hit it every 6 seconds.
Instead do this, which only reloads if the server returned.
You can even change done to success so it only retries if there was a successful reload.

```js
var tId, 
    valvonta = function() {
      clearTimeout(tId); // in case there is one running 
      var kaavio = 38;
      $.post("hae_tilanteet.php", {
        kaavio: kaavio
      }).done(function(data) {
        $('#valvonta').html(data);
        tId = setTimeout(valvonta,6000);
      });
    };

$(function(){
  //Pass the function reference to be executed after 6 sec
  tId = setTimeout(valvonta,6000);

  $('#kaaviotaulukko').on("click",function(){
    valvonta(); 
    // never alert in a page with timeout/interval - it blocks
    console.log('Radio Box has been changed!'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Why is this a better way?

Comment: So, if I do not use alert, then it is OK to use setInterval?

Comment: No. use setTimeout from the done/success - it works the same but waits for the server to respond